# ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray) on CNN classifiction

Tags: python, numpy, conv-neural-network

Our Model looks like:

```
model_name = 'model_inceptionResNetV2_aug'
def get_model_inceptionResNetV2(input_shape):    
    
    model = InceptionResNetV2(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, 
                        input_shape=input_shape, pooling='avg')

    perut_input = Input(input_shape)
    bokong_input = Input(input_shape)

    encoded_perut = model(perut_input)
    encoded_bokong = model(bokong_input)

    # Flattening the output for the dense layer
    fout2 = Flatten()(encoded_perut)
    fout3 = Flatten()(encoded_bokong)

    # Getting the dense output
    dense = Dense(2)
    dout2 = dense(fout2)
    dout3 = dense(fout3)

    # Concatenating the final output
    out = Concatenate(axis=-1)([dout2, dout3])

    # output berat 
    dense_out = Dense(12, activation='softmax') #jumlah kelas
    final_out = dense_out(out)


    # output
    model_densenet = Model(inputs=[perut_input, bokong_input],outputs=final_out)

    return model_densenet
```

I got error message:

```
    1/11 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 3.1334 - accuracy: 0.2159/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:78: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-25-9d2c5fd65355> in <module>()
          1 model.fit(train_batch, epochs = epochs,
          2                       verbose = 1, callbacks = [stop_train_callback, model_checkpoint_callback, history],
    ----> 3                       validation_data = valid_batch)
    
    1 frames
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
        104       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
        105   ctx.ensure_initialized()
    --> 106   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
        107 
        108 
    
    ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type numpy.ndarray).
```

I tried to convert the dtype into its best fits: string and float32 (for numeric and target class). Should the target class dtype converted into 'object'? also tried but still not working,

Any clues please.

Comment: Please, list the imports of your code, and and how did you call your code. Check how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: The problem most likely is with the data, not the model.  Is it really consistent?  Same shape for all elements of the batch?  There have been many SO about this kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

hpaulj is absolutely right, since it's a CNN, my data are images, I re-resized  them, thanks to https://bulkresizephotos.com reupload all the images and viola!! Thanks.